# This is my code, a new photo is added, but the previous photo is not deleted Does anyone know what the problem is?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Productid,Groupid,Productname,ProductText,Productimage,Productprice,Productdate")] Products products,HttpPostedFileBase Productimage)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(Productimage != null)
                {
                    if (products.Productimage != null)
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("/Content/images/") + products.Productimage);
                    }
                    products.Productimage = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(Productimage.FileName);
                    Productimage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Content/images/"+products.Productimage));
                }
                db.Entry(products).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Groupid = new SelectList(db.Groups, "Groupid", "Grouptitle", products.Groupid);
            return View(products);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint at the `File.Delete()` to see if it is executed? I suspect either `if (products.Productimage != null) ` is false or the path may not be correct in the `File.Delete()`

Comment: Have you supply the `Productimage` from view. if not add this line inside form `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Productimage)`